# How to detect and remove invalid unicode sequences in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, unicode

Given an input string, generate an output string where all invalid sequences are either removed or replaced with U+FFFD.

Is there a better method than implementing a state-machine char-by-char, or a non-native node.JS module available?

Invalid sequences are, for example, orphaned surrogates `"\uD800"`, or other invalid multi-char sequences.

Comment: What else are you trying to remove other than surrogates? Do you want to remove the not-a-characters like U+FFFF as well? (This will be annoying for non-BMP characters.) Or the not-yet-allocated code points?

Comment: Non-characters and unassigned code points may be used internally by applications to no ill-effect so I don't want to remove them. If there are no properly invalid sequences other than orphaned surrogates, then that's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex needed to match invalid sequences depends on what you want to include. To replace orphaned surrogates with U+FFFD, you can use something like this:

```
var surrogates = /[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]|[\ud800-\udfff]/g;
str = str.replace(surrogates , function ($0) {
    return $0.length > 1 ? $0 : '\ufffd';
});
```

If you use the [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) library with its [Unicode addons](http://xregexp.com/plugins/), you can use the `\p{Cs}` or `\p{Surrogate}` Unicode category instead of `[\ud800-\udfff]`. Using XRegExp will also give you easy access to other potentially relevant Unicode properties such as `\p{Noncharacter_Code_Point}`, `\p{Co}` or `\p{Private_Use}`, and `\p{Cn}` or `\p{Unassigned}`.

Since you're using Node.js, you can [install](https://github.com/slevithan/XRegExp#installation-and-usage) XRegExp via npm using `npm install xregexp`. XRegExp's npm module automatically includes the Unicode addons.